# Valuing an option

Tags: probability, finance

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Analyst report says that stock will be taken over with probability $50$%. If it’s not taken over, it’ll
> move to $5$ dollars with $40$% chance, and to 0 dollars with $60$% chance. If it’s taken over, it’ll move to
> $15$ dollars with $80$% chance, and $x$ with $20$% chance. The stock is trading at $10$ dollars. How much
> would you pay, assuming no time value of money, for the option to buy the stock at $22$ dollars after
> everything settles? This means you get to see if it’s taken over or not, and then get to see where it

Supposedly the correct answer is $\$0.80$ but I can't seem to arrive at that answer. Here is my thinking:

The value of the call ($C$) should be such that the expected payout for the contract is $\$0$.

$\frac34$ possible outcomes result in stock prices below the strike price, therefore the call is out of the money and we lose $\$C$. The probabilities for each of these outcomes sum to $0.9$.

In the last case, where the stock is worth $\$x$ with probability $0.1$, our payout is $x-22-C$

Therefore the price of the call C should be $-0.9C + 0.1(x-22-C) = 0$ solved for $C$. But I cannot figure how to possibly derive a value for the option without knowing $x$ (or at the very least the distribution of x) because if x was hypothetically infinitely large, the option would be worth a very large amount, whereas if $x = 0$, the option would be worthless (it is guaranteed to expire out of the money)

I also cannot figure out if I need to incorporate the spot price ($\$10$) into a calculation like this, although my work seems intuitively correct to me.

Comment: I think the point of including the spot price is so that you can determine what $x$ is.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen how does the spot price influence x in the context of this hypothetical problem?

Comment: If you can calculate the expected value of the call payout, and thus determine the call price, you should be able to calculate the expected value of the stock and thus determine the stock price.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I'm sorry, I don't really understand

Comment: The expected value of the stock price needs to be the spot price. Since you already know the spot price, this gives you enough information to solve for x

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen that's the piece I was missing! Thank you so much!